# Calling bash script from perl in nonbloking way and get a pid of this new background process

Tags: linux, bash, perl, nonblocking, pid

I have a bash script, which I ran from command line with `env`, redirecting its output to `log.txt`

```
env FOO=hello BAR=world ./myscript &> log.txt
```

I wanna run a few nonblocking instances of  `myscript` from perl in **background**.

And in its turn **perl** script is ran from another bash script `mainScript` by this way:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
perlScript.pl | tee main-log.txt
```

I know, I can do it using perl `system()` call in a loop like this

```
my $result = system("env FOO=hello BAR=world ./myscript &> log.txt &");
```

I use `fork` and `exec` calls from perl like this to run `myscript` in background and get its pid:

```
$run_cmd = "./myscript";
$run_cmd.= " &> log.txt";

defined(my $pid = fork) or die "$0: fork: $!\n";
if (!$pid) {  # child code is here

    $ENV{FOO} = 'hello';
    $ENV{BAR} = 'world';

    exec "exec $run_cmd";
    die "$0: failed to exec sh: $!\n";

}

# parent code continues here
print "PID of run_cmd: $pid \n";
```

But I found out that when I use pipe `|` and `tee` inside `mainScript`

```
| tee main-log.txt
```

I can't see output on screen after creating new proceess for `myScript` in **perl**

If I call `perlScript.pl` from `mainScript` without `tee` everything is ok.

How can I use `tee` in this case, or may be there is another way to redirect output from `mainScript`, that it would go both on **screen** and to some **log file**?

Comment: Your statement about fork/exec is wrong. Fork/exec will create a whole new process running independently from your Perl script.

Comment: I think the best solution to your problem will involve a change to myscript, namely moving the output redirection from the command line to inside the script. Is that possible in your situation, or are you not able to modify myscript at all? It's a pretty small change.

Comment: @MichaelAlbers I have updated my post clarifing scripts call hierarchy, which is `mainScript ->perlScript->myscript`. Without mainScript all works perfect with **fork/exec**, but if I run trought full hierarchy perlScript is blocked in some reason.

Comment: @Charley , unfortunately I can't change `myscript`.

Comment: What do you need the PID for?

Comment: @HåkonHægland I need to run many instances of `myscript`, and I need their pids to communicate with them.

Comment: Ok :)  then why didn't the solution by @melpomene below work? Do you call the Perl scripts from a Perl script or from a Bash script. Your question is a little bit confusing..

Comment: @HåkonHægland I call bash scripts from perl scripts which is called from another bash script :)

Comment: @MichaelAlbers I found out that **fork / exec** works fine if I don't use `tee` in the parent bash script. Thanks to @melpomene

Answer (score 1):

This is untested, but can't you just do this?

```
defined(my $pid = fork) or die "$0: fork: $!\n";
if (!$pid) {
    $ENV{FOO} = 'hello';
    $ENV{BAR} = 'world';
    exec 'exec ./myscript &> log.txt';
    die "$0: failed to exec sh: $!\n";
}
# parent process here, child pid is in $pid
```

You could even do the output redirection in perl, saving a call to the shell:

```
    open STDOUT, '>', 'log.txt' or die "$0: log.txt: $!\n";
    open STDERR, '>&', \*STDOUT or die "$0: dup(stdout): $!\n";
    exec './myscript';
    die "$0: ./myscript: $!\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use *[open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html)*:

```
my $pid = open(my $h, "$cmd |");
```

Then you can read the output of *cmd* from handle *h*:

```
while (<$h>) {
    print "$_\n";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use IPC::Open3 perl module - https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Open3